# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \ln \binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \ln \binom{2n}{n}.$$

$\underline{\bf{My\;\;Try}}::$ Let $\displaystyle y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \ln \binom{2n}{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \ln \left(\frac{(n+1)\cdot (n+2)\cdot (n+3)\cdots (n+n)}{(1)\cdot (2)\cdot (3)\cdots (n)}\right)$

$\displaystyle y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \left\{\ln \left(\frac{n+1}{1}\right)+\ln \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)+\ln \left(\frac{n+3}{3}\right)+\cdots+\ln \left(\frac{n+n}{n}\right)\right\}$

$\displaystyle y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \sum_{r=1}^{n}\ln \left(\frac{n+r}{r}\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \sum_{r=1}^{n}\ln \left(\frac{1+\frac{r}{n}}{\frac{r}{n}}\right)$

Now Using Reinman Sum

$\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln (x+1)dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln (x)dx =  \ln (2)$

My Question is , Is there is any method other then that like Striling Approximation OR Stolz–Cesàro theorem OR Ratio Test

If yes then please explain here

Thanks

Comment: do see this great answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/654350/72031

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320846/show-that-that-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-binom2nn-4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} = 2^{2n}$ and $\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n} \ge \binom{2n}{k}$ for all $0 \le k \le 2n$, we have

$$
\frac{2^{2n}}{2n+1}\le \binom{2n}{n} \le 2^{2n}
\quad\implies\quad \log 2 - \frac{\log{(2n+1)}}{2n} \le \frac{1}{2n} \log \binom{2n}{n} \le \log 2$$
Since $\quad\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n} = 0\quad$, 
we get $\quad\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2n}\log\binom{2n}{n} = \log 2$.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the elegant demonstration given by achille hui, I think that the simplest manner to solve this problem is to use Stirling approximation.

---

At the first order, Stirling's approximation is $n! = \sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n$. It is very good. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation. They have a very good page for that. For sure, you need to express the binomial coefficient as the ratio of factorials. Try that and you will be amazed to see how simple becomes your problem.

Comment: Thanks Claude Leibovici , would you like to explain me how can we get using Atriling approximation.

Comment: I forgot to mention a simpler formula for large values of n. It is Lon[n!] = n Log[n] - n

Comment: @Neal. Thanks for editing my post.