# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {(n!)^{\frac {1}{n}}}{n}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{n}\ln {2n \choose n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have two questions:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {(n!)^{\frac {1}{n}}}{n}$$ and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{n}\ln {2n \choose n}$$

I realised that I had to do this with the help of integration, and in both cases I had to come to the same situation $\int_{0}^{1}\ln \space xdx$. But then I'm having $(x\times ln\space x-x)|_{0}^{1}$ and am stuck in the $0\times ln \space 0$ thing. What should I do with it?

Comment: For the first one, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171904/limit-of-a-sequence-involving-root-of-a-factorial-lim-n-to-infty-fracn).

Comment: @DavidMitra, the second answer to that question dectly states $\int_{0}^{1}ln \space xdx=-1$, but I am stuck there.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) and [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties)

Comment: For the second, see [evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\cdot \ln \binom{2n}{n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/541232) and [Limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \log{2n\choose n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/580393).

Answer (score 0):

A simple substitution lets you see whats happening. Substitute $x=1/y$ into the limit so that it becomes $$\frac{-ln(y)}{y}.$$ As x approaches zero y approaches infinity, and it's a little more intuitive that the above limit should go to zero. You can prove it with L'Hopital.