# How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/n} = l$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Suppose that $a_n > 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}/a_n =l$$.

How to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{1/n} = l \;?$$

My solution: let 
$$b_n = a_{n+1}/a_n$$

Then

$$b_1 b_2 \cdots b_{n-1} = a_{n}/a_1$$.

Do we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} (b_1 \cdots b_{n-1})^{1/n} = l\;?$

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$b_n \to l \to \ln b_n \to \ln l \to \dfrac{\ln b_1 + \ln b_2 +\cdots \ln b_n}{n} \to \ln l$ by Cesaro theorem, and you are done.