# Elementary way to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Tags: limits

Let $a_n \gt 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The convergence radius of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is $\frac{1}{q}$ with $q = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ or $q = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, if these limits exist. Therefore the $\lim$s must be identical.

However I was wondering whether there exists a more elementary way to show this identity? (Or generally any other way?)

Comment: "Therefore the limsups must be identical." No. Find a counterexample. (And the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_nz^n$ with positive terms is not always the inverse of $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1}/a_n$.)

Comment: What are $a_n$, functions or numbers?

Comment: @JankoBracic: Real numbers.

Comment: @Did: Oh, your‘re right. Well, then I should assume the existence of both limits. I‘ll edit the question.

Comment: @Keba But what is then the convergence radius of $\sum a_n$?

Comment: @JankoBracic: I added a $z^n$ there.

Comment: @Keba Ok, now it is clear :)

Comment: If the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ be exist then the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ will be exist. [click here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287932/convergence-of-ratio-test-implies-convergence-of-the-root-test)

Comment: Intuitively, this is not surprising, since both limits are ways of saying that the sequence asymptotically resembles a geometric sequence, with the ratio being the limit.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n Probably also other questions linked [to 69386](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/69386) and [to 76743](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/76743).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general relation is
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mathstrut a_n} \le
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mathstrut a_n}  \le
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \quad \text{(*)}
$$
provided that all $a_n$ are positive. It follows that if 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exists then 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mathstrut a_n}$ exists as well and they are equal.

To prove the rightmost inequality, define $S := \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N \in \mathbb N$
such that 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < S + \epsilon \quad \text{ for } n \ge N \, .
$$
$$
  \implies a_n < a_N \, (S + \epsilon)^{n - N} \quad  \text{ for }  n \ge N 
$$
$$
  \implies \sqrt[n]{\mathstrut a_n} < (S + \epsilon) \sqrt[n]{ a_N (S + \epsilon)^{-N}}
$$
$$
 \implies \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mathstrut a_n} \le S + \epsilon \, .
$$

The leftmost inequality can be proved in the same way, or by taking
the reciprocals.

That the convergence radius $R$ of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ can be
determined with the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) or
with the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)
is a *consequence* of the above relation (*), not the other way around.

But note that the tests are slighty different: 
$$
  \frac 1R = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\mathstrut |a_n|}
$$
holds even if the limit does not exists.
$$
  \frac 1R = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigr|
$$
is only valid if the *limit* on the right-hand side exists. You cannot 
generally replace the $\lim$ by $\limsup$ in the ratio test.